# i18n cakephp 1.3 internatialization

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and I'm having some trouble with **i18n**.
There are about 10,000 strings in my project and that's okay. But I'm having huge problems with some of the strings:

First string in code:

```
<?=  sprintf( __('bla bla bla <span id="count">%s</span> bla', true), $count ); ?>
```

This string in *.po file:

```
msgid "bla bla bla <span id=\\\"count\\\">%s</span> bla"
```

In crowdin:

```
bla bla bla <span id=\"companies-count\">%s</span> bla
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Second string doesn't load from *.pot file:

```
<? __('bla'); ?>
```

They're all ok with the syntax. I think that this is due to the fact that I have string: `<? __('Bla'); ?>`, which fall to pot file instead of lowercase bro. Help please and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any HTML markup in the string you want to translate. So you want to put your `<span>` tags in the replacement text:-

```
<?=  sprintf( __('bla bla bla %s bla', true), '<span id="count">' . $count . '</span>' ); ?>
```

This will give you `bla bla bla %s bla` in your .po file.

Your second issue (you should really be asking this as a separate Stackoverflow question) is as far as I am aware that the strings are not case sensitive.

I think you can use `__d()` to apply a 'domain' to the string to distinguish it (but I'm not 100% sure on that):-

```
__d('lower', 'bla');
```